# SIMCOM SIM7000G power supply design testing LTspice

Tags: power-supply, edge, gprs, simcom

According to the [datasheet SIM7000 _Hardware Design_V1.05](https://github.com/mcore1976/sim7000gpstracker/blob/master/SIM7000%20Hardware%20Design_V1.05.pdf) in section **3.1 Power Supply**,

> On VBAT pads, when module works on EDGE or GPRS mode, the ripple current is up to 2A typically. For steady voltage, the power supply capability must be up to 2A."
> In order to avoid the voltage dropped down more than 300mV, the load capacitor on VBAT pads must be up to 300uF."

According to figure 5: VBAT voltage drop during burst emission (EDGE/GPRS)
and the recommended circuit in Figure 6: Power supply application circuit

I can I test this circuit using LTSpice or "any other open source simulator."  While I can find components like capacitors, resistors and inductors it was hard to find the TVS diode provided in the datasheet (one of the recommended TVS is PESDHC3D3V3U.)

I tried to make a model in the LTspice but I don't know why the simulation did not work. [Here is the model on github.](https://github.com/MohammedSciUp/PESDHC3D3V3U-model)

[image]

Comment: Can you ask a specific question?

Comment: the basic question, how to make a test model to verify the selection of the above circuit in the (SIM7000 _Hardware Design_V1.05) in the provided link above because I have seen several schematics where they used other schematics diagrams and different power regulation devices (LDO / buck converters) I wanted to follow the documentation by verifying its selection using simulation software LTSpice (free one) the circuit I that I need to test is described in the section 3.1 of the SIM7000 _Hardware Design_V1.05 (Figure 6)

Comment: You have anode and cathode swapped.  You should probably post your entire LTspice circuit.  I think your troubles are likely going to extend beyond just the TVS diode.